# How to create a virtual directory in IIS using Cake

Tags: iis, cakebuild

Is there a way to create virtual directories in IIS using a Cake build script?

I found the [Cake.IIS](https://github.com/SharpeRAD/Cake.IIS) addin, which allows creating app pools and sites, but not virtual directories.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Applications have been in the addin since its first release under [SiteAliases](https://github.com/SharpeRAD/Cake.IIS/blob/master/src/IIS/Aliases/SiteAliases.cs)
I've updated the ReadMe accordingly. Feel free to submit a PR if you want to change something but please can we do it at the source (Github) rather than a secondary site (Stackoverflow)...

Comment: Thanks a lot. BTW: for me, `AddSiteApplication()` only works if I also specify `ApplicationPool` and `VirtualDirectory` in the `ApplicationSettings`. E.g. `ApplicationPool = "DefaultAppPool", VirtualDirectory = "/NestedApp"`.

Comment: Feel free to submit a PR for any changes you would like implemented but again can we please have this conversation in Github where the project is located.

Answer (score 4):

Currently, there is nothing within Cake or any of the Cake Addin's that would provide this functionality for you.  That is not to say that you can't do it though.  You can add any arbitrary code that you want to your script.  There seems to be a good walk through of what is required here:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/carlosag/2006/04/17/microsoft-web-administration-in-iis-7/

Ideally, this functionality would be added to the Cake.IIS addin, so the best suggestion would be to raise a feature request issue on the GitHub repo, and see if this can get added.

Comment: Thanks! It seems there is even a fork of Cake.IIS, which would provide this functionality (https://github.com/rafalmaciag/Cake.IIS). But I'd prefer to use an "official" addin using the `#addin` directive.

Comment: So there is!  It would be great to have that merged into the Cake.IIS Addin that is on NuGet.org.  Could you reach out to rafalmaciag to see if he would submit a Pull Request?  We are in the process of starting to encourage people to add their addin's to the new Cake-Contrib organisation on GitHub: https://github.com/orgs/cake-contrib/dashboard which will hopefully prevent this type of forking, but we have literally only just started that organisation, and currently only my addin's are in there.

Comment: Apologies, the link I provided would require permissions to access the organisation, the link you have provided is the one you need.